# converting onCancel to functional component with react Hooks from class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm converting a class component to a functional component using React Hooks and for some reason my `onCancel` errors with `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

I'm not sure if I've done the conversion correctly.

**BEFORE**

```
    class ClosedCaptions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: props.isOpen,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.onCancel = this.onCancel.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchClosedCaption, fetchPersona } = this.props;
    fetchClosedCaption();
    fetchPersona();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.isUpdatingPersona !== this.props.isUpdatingPersona && this.props.isUpdatingPersona) {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: false,
      });
    }
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
    });
    this.props.restoreToSaved();
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true,
    });
  }
```

**AFTER**

```
 const ClosedCaptions = ({ isOpen, fetchClosedCaption, fetchPersona, restoreDefault }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslate();
  const [newIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(isOpen);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchClosedCaption();
    fetchPersona();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUpdatingPersona !== isUpdatingPersona && isUpdatingPersona) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  }

  const onCancel = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    restoreToSaved();
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }
```

Comment: `restoreToSaved` is a fn coming from props, either destructure it or pass the whole props object to your component. Although this is not the cause of the error. To which line does the error point?

Comment: Hi, I updated the code... hopefully this is enough now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isUpdatingPersona !== isUpdatingPersona && isUpdatingPersona) {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }
}
```

This is missing `, [isUpdatingPersona])`, and the `const` on the next line is triggering your `Unexpected token` error. To clarify, it should be written:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isUpdatingPersona !== isUpdatingPersona && isUpdatingPersona) {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }
}, [isUpdatingPersona])
```

with `isUpdatingPersona` declared *above* rather than *below* in order to be referenced as a dependency of the effect.

<sub>Normally I would close this as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" but since I already voted to close with "Needs debugging details" and subsequently retracted, I cannot vote to close this question.</sub>

Comment: isUpdatingPersona is not missing, it's further down as a constant. I just didn't add it because that's not the issue. There's a lot of code and I was trying to avoid copying pasting the entire thing.

Comment: @HelloL I'm not saying the variable is missing. I'm saying the closing parenthesis to the function invocation `useEffect()` is missing, along with the dependencies list as the second parameter. You should also get in the habit of declaring your local variables _above_ their usage rather than _below_, since `isUpdatingPersona` needs to be specified as a dependency to this effect in order to be correct.